# cygwin sed behaves differently in Jenkins Pipeline with \ in Path

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline, cygwin

Using Cygwin sed, on windows command prompt, sed takes `\\\` to convert a path to : e.g.

```
C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\\WorkArea\\\workspace\\\sources/g'
```

would result in C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources

But when I have to use the same in Jenkins pipeline, it takes `\\\\\\` in the path to convert it to single . Here is the command line I had to generate to give me 'C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources'

```
      stage('SED') 
      {
          steps {
                script {
                    cfgFile="MyCfg.xml"
                    dir(AutomationScripts) {
                        bat (""" cat MyCfg.xml | sed "s/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\\\\\WorkArea\\\\\\workspace\\\\\\sources/g" > newMyCfg.xml""")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update:** I experimented by changing quotes as mentioned in the comments, but nothing seemed to be changed. Here are the pipelines (starting with `bat`) and the results:

```
Pipeline: bat (" echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\\\\\WorkArea\\\\\\workspace\\\\\\sources/g' ")
Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\\WorkArea\\\workspace\\\sources/g'  
'C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources' 


Pipeline: bat (" echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'  | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\WorkArea\\workspace\\sources/g'")
Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources/g' 
'C:WorkAreaworkspacesources' 

Pipeline: bat ("""echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed "s/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\WorkArea\\workspace\\sources/g" """)
Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed "s/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources/g"  
'C:WorkAreaworkspacesources'

Pipeline: bat ("echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\\\WorkArea\\\\workspace\\\\sources/g'")
Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\WorkArea\\workspace\\sources/g' 
'C:WorkAreaworkspacesources' 


Pipeline: bat ("""echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed "s/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\\\WorkArea\\\\workspace\\\\sources/g" """)
Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed "s/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\WorkArea\\workspace\\sources/g"  
'C:WorkAreaworkspacesources'
```

Although, it was a bat call and supposed to behave the same as it happens at the command prompt.

Looks like Pipeline itself escaping \.

Any idea if I'm missing something here?

Comment: You are using different quotes around the sed expression.

Comment: @DougHenderson, just updated the post with some tests with quotes. It doesn't seem to be changing anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that that `groovy pipeline` script escapes `\`, so to get `C:\Program Files\Microsoft`, so have to use `\\` i.e. `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft`.
On the other hand, (Observed in Windows cygwin 64) `sed` takes `\\\` to get `\` as mentioned in my original post i.e. 
`C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\\WorkArea\\\workspace\\\sources/g'` 
 would result in `C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources`

So using sed in the `groovy pipeline`, at first `groovy` would do the escaping in the path string and then the result would be passed on to the `sed`, which would again do its own escaping on the string, so we have to add `\\\\\\` in our paths, which would be escaped by the `groovy` and it would become `\\\`. Then `sed` would escape `\\\` to a `\`. Here is the example I posted, is working like that:

```
Pipeline: bat (" echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES' | c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\\C:\\\\\\WorkArea\\\\\\workspace\\\\\\sources/g' ")

Output: C:\>echo 'PATH_TO_SOURCES'   | c:\cygwin64\bin\sed 's/PATH_TO_SOURCES/\C:\\\WorkArea\\\workspace\\\sources/g'  
'C:\WorkArea\workspace\sources'
```